# Play a tick sound every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I am implementing a timer, in which I want to play a tick/click sound every second. I am using an `AVAudioPlayer` for it now but it doesn't work fine.

Comment: show what you have tried ..

Comment: Declare the instance of `AVAudioPlayer` as global, not local instance variable.

Comment: thank you @vaibhav  but i got it fixed

Comment: thanks @pk456 i got the issue fixed

Comment: @kishan can you share your answer?

Comment: -(void)initTimerAudio
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/timerTick.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
  }

-(void)targetMethod{
    [audioPlayer play];
}